# With threading - python code gives error - Exception has occurred: TypeError object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

this is code without threading, it runs well (I want to recognise emotion which this code does)

```
from cv2 import LINE_4, imread
from fer import FER
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open Webcam")

def emotion_recog():

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions= ['emotion'], enforce_detection=False)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1,4)

        for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        cv2.putText(frame, result['dominant_emotion'], (50,50), font, 3, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
        #print(result['dominant_emotion'])
        #print(emotion_recog.result['dominant_emotion'])

        cv2.imshow('Original Video', frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I introduce threading It doesn't work - it gives error -
**Exception has occurred: TypeError
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()**

I want to capture emotion, send it to another function and display result based on emotion detected

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time
from threading import *

from cv2 import LINE_4, imread
from fer import FER
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

from deepface import DeepFace

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open Webcam")

current_mean = None

def emotion_recog():

    while True:
        result, frame = cap.read()
        result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions= ['emotion'], enforce_detection=False)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1,4)

        for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        cv2.putText(frame, result['dominant_emotion'], (50,50), font, 3, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
        #print(result['dominant_emotion'])
        #print(emotion_recog.result['dominant_emotion'])

        cv2.imshow('Original Video', frame)
            
        if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


t1 = Thread(target=emotion_recog)
t1.start()

cap.release()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your main thread starts the `emoticon_recog` thread, and then it immediately calls `cap.release()`. Meanwhile the new thread calls `cap.read()` in its top-level loop. I don't know `cv2`, but I don't think that's going to work. **Q:** The main thread creates `cap` and starts the video capture, but then `cap` is only ever _used_ inside the `emoticon_recog` function. The main thread doesn't do anything with `cap` except "release" it. Why not keep `cap` entirely within `emoticon_recog`? Why not create it there, start the capture there, read it there, and release it there?

Comment: it's always the same issue. people not following docs when they use `VideoCapture`. your code lacks the error checking that is required. `assert cap.isOpened()` **once**, and in the loop `if not result: break` right after cap.read()

Comment: Lines 46-47 should be placed before line 25.